# How to reset badge number for app icon using Firebase cloud function notification payload?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Current behaviour: UserA send another userB message, notification is triggered while app is in background, the badge number increases as more messages trigger notification. UserB opens notification, the badge value is set to 0 and minimize the app. User A send another message to userB while userB app in background, the badge value is not reset to 1, instead, it continues from the last accumulated value.

Desired Behaviour: Have badge value increment from 1 when userB receives new notifications instead of incrementing from last accumulated notification badge value.

Further: I have checked the firebase payload, it seems like the payload is sending the accumulated value and not resetting the value after userB already set the value to 0 client side.

Cloud function below:

```html
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
    var badgeCount = 1;
exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/Notifications/Messages/{pushId}').onWrite((change,context) => {
    console.log('Push notification event triggered for testing');
    console.log(change);
    const message = change.after.val();
    const senderUid = message.Sender;
    const receiverUid = message.SendTo;
    const chatMessage = message.Message;
    const senderName = message.SenderName;
    console.log(receiverUid);
    const promises = [];

    console.log('notifying ' + receiverUid + ' about ' + chatMessage + ' from ' + senderUid);

        const payload = {
            notification: {
                title: senderName,
                body: chatMessage,
                badge: badgeCount.toString(),
                sound: "default"
            }
        };

    badgeCount++;
        return admin
     .database()
     .ref("fcmToken").child(receiverUid)
     .once("value")
     .then(allToken => {
       if (allToken.val()) {
         const token = Object.keys(allToken.val());
         console.log(`token? ${token}`);
         return admin
           .messaging()
           .sendToDevice(token, payload)
           .then(response => {
             return null;
           });
       }
       return null;
     });
 });
```

Inside project appDelegate applicationDidBecomeActive and applicationWillEnterForeground.

```html
UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
```

Comment: I have fixed the question, hopefully it is easier to understand now.

Answer (score 0):

> While in the app, `didbecomeactive` I use UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0 to reset it to 0 upon opening the app.

This is fine to reset badge counter. but,

> However, the next time the notification is sent, the badge value starts at the previous incremented value again, e.g(5) instead of 1. Can someone explain/help what is going on here?

Here, you can not update badge counter from app side when push notification received.

iOS automatically update badge counter on app icon when push notification received with value of "badge" parameter of push notification payload. so, currently, you seems to send same value for "badge" in all notifications. so, if you send "badge" value "5". every time, badge value will be updated as "5".

so, you need to send proper badge value in notification payload from firebase function.

you may refer this google documentation for more details about "badge" parameter.: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support

Comment: I have a incremental variable count inside the cloud function that increase the badge value inside the payload, the number 5 was an example. My client side is indeed resetting the badge but the cloud function variable keeps the counter going and it just keeps increasing. How should i deal with that?

Answer (score 0):

Three parts to solving your issue given firebase

1.) Create a field mapped to the specific user in your db that tracks the notification count.

2.) Implement logic on the client to update the notification field in the db based on the users actions

3.) Handle updating the badge number on the client

Comment: The notification count is handled service side by cloud function inside the payload, hence serverless notification. You are saying I should create another database just to handle firebase notifications?

Comment: You need a way to track notifications over multiple sessions. Store a count of notifications in the same data structure you use to keep track of where the payload is going.